# C++ Split String into String Array

Tags: c++

I have a string, and need it split into a string array. The string is like this
Line 0|X|X|1|x|2|3|X, there is a few of these and there will always be 9 values into the array, with | being used as a splitter

I'm struggling to find something that isn't completely over complicated, so any help would be apperciated

Comment: looking at it that is massively over complex, I need a simple solution, that would be easy for someone learning to understand, I do web development in the past.

Comment: @CraigWeston *massively over complex*? what are you talking about. The highest ranked answer (unfortunately not the accepted one) gives a nice and short function `split()`, using `std::getline` (as David's answer below).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::string input = "0|X|X|1|x|2|3|X";
    std::istringstream ss(input);
    std::string token;

    while(std::getline(ss, token, '|')) {
       std::cout << token << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ODVumC

[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) can work with any string stream and accepts an arbitrary separator